# What is the proper way to extend a VG using a virtual disk

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

I have Ubuntu 18.04 Server installed on a VMware platform and I have two established VGs: rootvg is 500GB and hosts the O/S on /dev/sda. The datavg was 2TB and contains our PostgreSQL database environment, stored on /dev/sdb.

Recently, our team decided they need more disk space and so through the virtual machine they added another 1TB to the server for use by the datavg. They did this by changing the size of the virtual disk that they have currently in use. The problem with this is that I am not able to see the new disk space.

If I look at the datavg using vgdisplay, I see the old 2TB size:

```
vgdisplay datavg

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               datavg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  35
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                24
  Open LV               24
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <2.00 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              524287
  Alloc PE / Size       521216 / <1.99 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       3071 / <12.00 GiB
  VG UUID               vMxLPX-M3RG-BIVR-MsiF-dWtF-xLOl-4VCTGW
```

But if I check the disk in fdisk, it reports the new 3TB size.

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
    
Command (m for help): F
Unpartitioned space /dev/sdb: 3 TiB, 3298533834752 bytes, 6442448896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Start        End    Sectors Size
 2048 6442450943 6442448896   3T
```

I am not sure exactly what needs to be done to make the 2TB disk show up now as 3TB and give me access to the extra 1TB that was added. Originally, I thought I would need to add a new partition in fdisk, then use pvcreate and extendvg to add that as a new disk to the volume group. But I am now confused, because I expected datavg to already have at least one partition defined that is being used for the existing LVs on datavg. I cannot find any existing partitions on /dev/sdb.

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 3 TiB, 3298534883328 bytes, 6442450944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb32bb8b8
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?
Is there an easy way to alter the size of a VG after it was created and is in use, or do we have to back up VG contents, destroy VG, recreate VG larger, reload the backup?
Is there an equivalent to resize2fs but for VGs?

Thanks,

Steve N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question.
There is a command called "pvresize" that I was not aware of.

```
$ pvresize /dev/sdb 
  Physical volume "/dev/sdb" changed
  1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized

$ vgdisplay|more 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               datavg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  36
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                24
  Open LV               24
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <3.00 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              786431
  Alloc PE / Size       521216 / <1.99 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       265215 / 1.01 TiB
  VG UUID               vMxLPX-M3RG-BIVR-MsiF-dWtF-xLOl-4VCTGW
```

I now see /dev/sdb is showing 3TB for the VG size and 1TB of free space.

Thanks to anyone who happened to be checking this. Figured I'd post the answer I used, and see if anyone has any other comments. And of course, help others trying to learn Linux.